# Bookshelf.js return promise pending on fetchAll

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bookshelf.js

i am new at JS and Node. I am trying to make a task list in Expressjs. I have a bookshlef.js ODM. I traing to get all tasks from DB in function getAllTasks :

```
module.exports.getAllTasks = async function () {
let result = await  Task.fetchAll();
result = result.toJSON();
console.log(result);
}
```

and it print all data in console, but if I am trying to return data from function getAllTasks

```
module.exports.getAllTasks = async function () {
let result = await  Task.fetchAll();
result = result.toJSON();
return(result);
}
```

I get

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

I call it

```
var tasks = Application.getAllTasks();
console.log(tasks);
```

How can i return in getAllTasks a object with all data?

Comment: Try this `var tasks = await Application.getAllTasks();` or `Application.getAllTasks().then(tasks => {console.log(tasks)})`. Also in `getAllTasks` change `return(result)` to `return result`.

Comment: @Nithish thanks. This way  `Application.getAllTasks().then(tasks => {console.log(tasks)})` return object.